# How can I make an rx.py Observable from a stream such as stdin?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

I'm trying to get my head around the `rxpy` library for functional reactive programming (FRP) and I've already hit a roadblock.  I'm writing a small program that expects data to be streamed in via standard input (`sys.stdin`).

My question is therefore simple:  how can I create an `rx.Observable` instance that will asynchronously read from stdin?  Are there built-in mechanisms to create `Observable` instances from streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used `RxPy`, but I have a bit of familiarity with `RxJS`.

`RxPy` has [a number of built-in methods](http://rxpy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#rx/linq/observable_creation.py) that you could likely use for this purpose, but I'm inclined to create an Observable factory. Taking `ObservableCreation.from_array` as our guide, let's try that now. (Note: I haven't run this code, but it should get you most of the way there)

```
from rx.observable import Observable, ObservableMeta
from rx.anonymousobservable import AnonymousObservable
from rx.concurrency import current_thread_scheduler

class ObservableFile(Observable, metaclass=ObservableMeta):

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, readableFile, scheduler=None):
        scheduler = scheduler or current_thread_scheduler

        def subscribe(observer):
            def action(action1, state=None):
                try:
                    observer.on_next(readableFile.next())
                    action1(action)

                except StopIteration: # EOF
                    observer.on_completed()

            return scheduler.schedule_recursive(action)
        return AnonymousObservable(subscribe)
```

Then just use it like this:

```
res = rx.Observable.from_file(sys.stdin)
```

This will create an observable over each line of stdin until EOF. It's blocking, but there are [ways around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python). It can also be tuned with a different scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been playing with this today and

```
 d = rx.Observable.from_(sys.stdin).subscribe(print)
```

appears to work (echos lines to stdout). `from_` is an alias for `from_iterable`.
`d` is a Disposable to unsubscribe.